# Why does the "ColorRect" created in code not display?

Tags: gdscript, godot-3

When I try to create a "ColorRect" in code, it doesn't display. It still seems to exist, but I can't see it.

I am expecting to see both the rect created in the editor at `x=32 y=32` and the one created in GDScript at `x=128 y=32`, but I can only see the one created in the editor, as shown in the following picture:

[image: Cropped anotated screenshot showing the project described]

I am using version 3.5.2 of Godot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered by Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/139v3f2/when_i_try_to_create_a_colorrect_in_code_it/)

The default size when created in code is `Vector2(0,0)` instead of `Vector2(40,40)`.
This issue is fixed by giving the Rect a size.